# Как получить список всех изображений товара?

Tags: мойсклад-api

У меня такой вопрос на счет api json. Почему то я вижу миниатюру,tiny,и основное изображение,но где все остальные изображения,тут же их можно более 5 штук добавить,но при парсинге только 1 выдается,как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ ко всем изображениям появится только в JSON API 1.2